# Running a sh script from another script in cron

Tags: linux, bash, shell, cron

I have 2 shell script A.sh and B.sh

Inside A.sh I want to invoke B.sh based on certain conditions.
Something like below:

```
VAR=""
if [-z $VAR]:
then
    echo "running B"
    <path to B.sh>/B.sh > log.txt 2>&1
```

The A.sh is scheduled in as a cron job to be run every 15 min in crontab.

I have given B.sh and A.sh the needed permissions to execute.

When I run A from shell it is able to execute B if the condition is met however when running through crontab A is unable to invoke B. It does not throw any error as well.

Any help regarding this is appriciated.

Comment: Try running the script using set -x mode to get more info.

Comment: Something like? Post the *exact* code you are using, as your code has several errors involving the `[` command and an unspecified path to `B.sh`. If it's a relative path, then the problem can be explained by a difference between the working directory in effect when you ran `A.sh` from the shell and from `cron`.

Comment: Run your scripts through [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) and see what problems it spots.

Comment: Please show the relevant code and state the exact error. Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Partial scripts and *`<path to B.sh>`* are not helpful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/192982/calling-scripts-from-inside-other-scripts

Answer (score 0):

Shebang forgotten!?

```
#!/bin/bash
```

or

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is `bash`, `sh` or `ksh` your `if` need to be like this:

```
if [ -z "$VAR" ]
```

Also `VAR=""` do not unset the var (and with `-z` you check for unset variable), it assign empty string. So if you want to unset variable use command

```
unset VAR
```

And end the `if` structure with `fi`